# Apache/Django/mod_wsgi - [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, django, permission-denied

I am using Django + Apache + mod_wsgi and defined two applications: a test one - `polls` and `forecast`.

Suddenly I got into a problem when I try to access from Django server the `index.html` (main) page of `forecast` app - I get the error

> permission denied

Initially everything worked fine and I do not identify an error which I made. 
To mention that the access to `polls` app which is located into same project and directory `myproject` works fine.

> ```
> ===error 'forecast' app ====
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/florian/workdev/myproject/upload/index.html'
> Request Method:     GET
> Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/forecast/
> Django Version:     2.1.4
> Exception Type:     PermissionError
> Exception Value:    
>
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/florian/workdev/myproject/upload/index.html'
>
> Exception Location:   /home/florian/workdev/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loaders/filesystem.py in get_contents, line 23
> Python Executable:  /home/florian/workdev/venv/bin/python
> Python Version:     3.5.2
> Python Path:    
>
> ['/home/florian/workdev/myproject',
>  '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
>  '/usr/lib/python3.5',
>  '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>  '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
>  '/home/florian/workdev/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
>
> Server time:  Wed, 19 Dec 2018 18:57:44 +0000
> ```

Comment: Can you show the apache configuration?

Comment: I am trying to access from Django server, not yet from Apache. I discovered that if I change to empty list the templates/Dirs from settings.py, I can access now the index.html (located in forecast_app/templates) but I get same error when I try to access a different folder: 'upload' PermissionError at /forecast/upload/

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'upload/test_OK.csv'

Request Method:  POST
Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/forecast/upload/
Django Version:  2.1.4
Exception Type:  PermissionError
Exception Value:  

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'upload/test_OK.csv'

Comment: Apache config is (again I am using Django for now) -  Alias /static /home/florian/django/myproject/myproject/static
    <Directory /home/florian/workdev/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/florian/workdev/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
           Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/florian/workdev/myproject python-home=/home/florian/workdev/venv
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/florian/workdev/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

Comment: Try giving correct chmod permisions to upload folder

Answer (score 2):

I was using Apache+flask+mod_wsgi and faced similar issue with wsgi [error 13] permission denied.
This was happening because I had not configured WSGIDaemonProcess and WSGIProcessGroup with user privileges in apache2.conf file.
To fix this I did something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.site1.com
CustomLog logs/www.site1.com-access_log common
ErrorLog logs/ww.site1.com-error_log

WSGIDaemonProcess www.site1.com user=joe group=joe processes=2 threads=25
WSGIProcessGroup www.site1.com

...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.site2.com
CustomLog logs/www.site2.com-access_log common
ErrorLog logs/www.site2.com-error_log

WSGIDaemonProcess www.site2.com user=bob group=bob processes=2 threads=25
WSGIProcessGroup www.site2.com

...
</VirtualHost>
```

Refer this Doc for more details [Doc](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html)